# How to refresh/ redraw MPart

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-juno, eclipse-kepler

Is there is any way to redraw or refresh the `MPart` so that following method will call again.

```
@PostConstruct
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
 }
```

Because I want to show one SWT control in this view on some conditions.

Comment: Probably better to change the visibility of the control rather than try and recreate the whole part.

Comment: @greg-449 what it means can you please elaborate.

Comment: I mean create the control in `createPartControl` but call `setVisible(false)` and exclude it from the layout (`GridData.exclude = true`). When you want to show the control `setVisible(true)`, remove the exclude and call `layout(true)` on the composite.